# wireshark capture sip traffic and save an XML file with a specific format

Tags: centos, sip, asterisk, wireshark, tshark

I want to be able to capture SIP traffic and save the trace as XML file with an specific format , there is any way to do this with just wireshark - tshark commands ? FYI this will run in a Centos server .
The only way i found to create the specific format is by running a Perl script to format the XML file but is would be way better if I could do all with just wireshark?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tshark has options to convert a PCAP file to Text. Or you could capture it in a PDML or PSML format and then have a converter routine to your own XML format. And considering that wireshark if modifiable, you could tweak a plugin to do this differently. But i more inclined to build a converter process that parses the native pcap to what you like. So your raw data has all the information and you can freely keep changing the converter routine.

**For Text Conversion -**

tshark -V -r -T pdml "17c4d2c0-69cd-11e4-ae3e-9d5dee8b7eac.pcap" > capture.xml

**For Capture as PDML / PSML -**

tshark -T pdml

I am inclined to think that there could be options to directly covert to PSML like the Text converter from the PCAP.